# Google Assistant action access API that I do not own

Tags: api, authentication, oauth-2.0, actions-on-google, google-home

I have gone thru the documentation of [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) but I am still unclear about the mechanics on how to build an action using a API that I do not own support Oauth2.

Let say, I want to allow Ebay users to ask "Hey Google, ask Ebay, has my order shipped?".  With that question, I need to access user transactions on Ebay via API and I have no control over how Ebay OAuth2 endpoints and parameters.

Please let me know if you have done it or know a good example.  Eventually, I will want to call API from various sites (some kind of mashup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to approach this in two parts - having an account in your system for each user and linking your account to their Assistant account.

The account in your system will store the credentials you need from them (usually an OAuth token) to access the API for a service on their behalf. This is typically done by having them log into your website and authorizing you to access the other service through an OAuth dance.

In the second part, the roles are slightly reversed. The Assistant now needs to get authorization from the user to access *your service* through an OAuth dance of some sort. This is what Account Linking does - it gets an OAuth token *for your service* to the Assistant so it can pass it to you and so you can verify who the user is.

Once you know who the user is (through the Assistant), you can then access their account on your service, get the auth tokens you need to access their account on another service (such as Ebay), and perform those actions.

In some situations, you can verify who the user is without Account Linking. The easiest is to require the user to sign into your service using Google Sign In (or otherwise get their Google account authorization to your service) and then use [Google Sign In for Assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) to have the Assistant verify to you which Google account they're using. As above, you can then look up this account in your system and get the authorizations you have for the other services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was also what I thought on doing but I was hoping there are shortcuts for this use case which is probably quite common.  Basically, my app will be a proxy for GA.  It hits my app, my apps turns around and calls other API.  For operations that I plan to provide some value added, I have to use this pattern anyway.  But some simple operation like my example above, I was hoping GA could call the original API directly.

Comment: No. The Google Assistant is just like a web browser in this sense. There is nothing built-into JavaScript or HTML that will automatically call Ebay. Someone has to write that and send the information in a format that the browser can handle. In the same way - someone has to write the responses in a way the Google Assistant can understand.